# Calling dispatch from route guard results in recursive calling of guard

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-router-guards

I am using angular version 14, however I am having issues being able to update a value in the ngrx store from a route guard.

the scenario is that once a user has logged in, I call a endpoint which will tell me if their cookie is valid and if so will return their username which I would like to put into the store, because this call is done in the guard I would like to use the data already fetched instead of calling the endpoint a second time on page load.

**guard**

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.authService.isCookieValid().pipe(
      map(result => {
        if(result?.username == null)
          return false;
        this.store.dispatch(setUsername({ data: result}))
        return true;
      }));
  }
```

**Reducer**

```
export const authReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(setUsername, (state, { data }) => {
    return ({
      ...state,
      user: <User>{ username: data.username! },
    });
  }),
```

I am not using any effects only using the reducer to set the store value, however the above code results in the route guard being cancelled and called repeatedly forever.
I have found that using the same code but changing

```
this.store.dispatch(setUsername({ data: result}))
```

to

```
setTimeout(() => this.store.dispatch(setUsername({ data: result})), 1);
```

does fix the problem but feels very hacky, any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I suspect your `isCookieValid` method doesn't emit only once and then complete. Would that be correct?

Comment: isCookieValid is an api call, so I would of thought it would only emit once per time the guard is hit?